# Filter column by value inside and get index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, multiple-columns

I would like to get an other dataframe fill with columns which have value greater or equal to `1`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': '0 1 0 0 1 2'.split(),
               'B': '0.1 0.2 0 0.5 0 0.1'.split(),'C':'0.1 0.2 0 0.5 0 0.1'.split()})

   A    B    C
0  0  0.1  0.1
1  1  0.2  0.2
2  0    0    0
3  0  0.5  0.5
4  1    0    0
5  2  0.1  0.1
```

For instance, I would to get `df2` like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': '0 1 0 0 1 2'.split()})
```

If I try df2=df2[df2.values.astype(float) >= 1] I keep my three columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a boolean mask where at least some value in a column is >= 1.  Then I use this mask on both the data and the columns to produce a new dataframe.

I utilize numpy for the masking.

```
# convert to floats and define mask
v = df.values.astype(float)
mask = (v >= 1).any(0)

# assign new dataframe with masked data and masked columns
# just incase there where multiple columns that satisfied.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(v.T[mask].T, columns=df.columns[mask])
df2
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

[image]

***df 1000 times as long***

```
df = pd.concat([df.T for _ in range(1000)], ignore_index=True).T
```

[image]

Comment: wau, your solution is surprisingly faster, +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) what means get values `greater` or `equal`, then filter by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) at least one `True` and last [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by columns with `ix`:

```
print (df.astype(float).ge(1, axis=1))
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4   True  False  False
5   True  False  False

print (df.astype(float).ge(1, axis=1).any())
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool

#sample data are strings, so first cast to float
df2 = df.ix[:, df.astype(float).ge(1, axis=1).any()]
print (df2)
   A
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  1
5  2
```

It also works with:

```
df2 = df.ix[:, (df.astype(float) >= 1).any()]
print (df2)
   A
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  1
5  2
```

Comment: straight forward, pure pandas, very efficient +1